# How to integrate dialogflow with floating chat in website

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I want to using Dialogflow framework within website . I know dialogflow offers the website integration as widget but.I want to use in it a custom designed floating chatbox in website.Like a chatbox which hovers in the corner of the page.How can i integrate with such chatUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way in dialogflow to do so. You will just have to create a simple chat window in html/angular or in any framework you want to design. You can just capture user-entered query & make an ajax call & pass it to dialogflow. Again that depends on the api version that you're using. Dialogflow offers you v1/v2 apis, which itself changes the request format. Please have a look at code below (used v1 api):

```
function captureUserQuery() {
         var text = jQuery(".my-text").val();
         dialogflowApi(text);  
}

function dialogflowApi(text) {
         jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20170712",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
                query: text,
                lang: "en",
                sessionId: "chatbot"
            }),
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("success");
                // Here you will get the response to your query in json, you will have to parse it based on the type it has like text, image, card etc. & show it to user. 
                parseResponse(response); // function to parse your response. 
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });
}
```

Hope this answers your query. Let me know if you have any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by updating the iframe tag provided by dialogflow. You can put any html page you want inside the iframe tag. Also you can add a floating button/icon to activate it:

```
<iframe height="430" width="350" src="https://bot.dialogflow.com/kjhdfjhfjfh">

<your custom designed floating chatbox in website html>

</iframe>
```