# Integrating Diagflow with website as Popup

Tags: popup, dialogflow-es, integration, chatbot, squarespace

I am not great at coding, I have my website on Squarespace and I have created a chatbot using Dialogflow. While clicking on Web-Demo, I get this code:

```html
<iframe
    allow="microphone;"
    width="350"
    height="430"
    src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/xxxxx">
</iframe>
```

When I am pasting the code in footer section of my Squarespace website, it displays the chatbot in the footer as section. I want it to pop-up like we have on other websites. It would be great if someone can help me out and guide me with the change I have to make in the your code to make it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely a matter of applying `position:fixed` to the element via [the CSS Editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor). You also may be able to further customize the chat module with your own HTML, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55146097/5338581).

As an example, if you were to give your `iframe` an additional attribute of, say, `id="chatbot"`, then your CSS might look something like:

```
#chatbot {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow is a very good bot builder platform, but there is no direct way to integrate an agent with your website. The reason is that they do not provide a specific widget for the browser. The web demo integration is for demo purposes only and is not customizable. There are also two possible ways to integrate the Dialogflow bot into your website.

1. Once you have trained your agent, you can add the Dialogflow API to your website. (I would not recommend this method as it requires a lot of coding knowledge) For more information on this, please refer to this [article](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/dialogflow-tutorial-create-chatbots/).
2. Integrate with a web-chat plugin tool like [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/home), as they provide a 3-easy steps to integrate with the Dialogflow and add the JS code provided for the chat widget to popup on your Squarespace website. Also, the chat widget UI can be customised according to your needs. To integrate Dialogflow with Kommunicate please refer to this [article](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/integrate-bot-using-dialogflow-in-kommunicate/) and To add kommunicate with the Squarespace website in just 5 easy steps [Read here](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/squarespace-live-chat-software-for-website/), It may help you better.

PS. I work for kommunicate.